# Sequelize order with condition

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I am trying to add order in the query but to be based on condition.

The goal is to order users that are in a relation but based on a flag they have

**Include in the main query has properties like this**

```
include: { model: User, include: { model: User, as: 'parent' } }
```

Now on the client, I have 2 columns in the table that have the same property name, but one has property parent and the other does not.

**example:**

```
order: [[ { model: User }, 'name', sorting ]]
```

When I do ordering like above I am sorting with name property but including both User and User as a parent. Is there a way that I can separate these two?

I saw in the docs that sorting is possible with using sequelize.fn but can't find any examples with it. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

To order the parent association which is it a User as well you can do the following

```
[[‘name’, sorting], [{model: User, as: 'Parent'}, 'name',   sorting]]
```

That should work and hope will help you !